# How to concatenate date and time field from excel source via SSIS

Tags: datetime, ssis, sql-server-2016, visual-studio-2019

I have a CSV source with 2 columns, date and time, like this

```
dateOfPurchase: 04/04/2019 00:00
timeOfPurchase: 16:50:00
```

I was investigating a bit and found that I could do it with a *Derived column transformation*

I would like to combine both in just `1`, so the output would be

```
dateOfPurchase: 04/04/2019 16:50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a derived column with the following expression:

```
LEFT([DateField],10) + " " + LEFT([TimeField],5)
```

If you want to Parse the value to Date type try using the following expression:

```
(DT_DATE)(LEFT([DateField],10) + " " + [TimeField])
```